# Can I Insert Records into a SQL Table passing a bean as values using Apache Commons DBUtils

Tags: java, sql, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using Java to access a MS SQL server.  I am looking for a simple way to import data into various tables without having to write large sql querys.  Some of these tables have 30 some columns.

I found the apache commons dbutils library and it works really well to read data from tables and map rows to beans.  I can't seem to find any code that uses the same principlea to insert data into a table passing the bean as the data values

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try jpa/hibernate?

Comment: I'm trying to do this simply without using a framework like that or spring etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be nice, however, I don't think it's possible. One way is to create a static function inside of your POJO class to get the "Insertion SQL statement". Although you must maintain the ordering between the two functions (insertion and parameters).

**Employee.java**

```
public static String getEmployeeInsertStatement()
{
    //if you add more fields, increase this integer
    int numberOfParameters = 5;

    String insertion = "INSERT INTO employee\n"
            + "(name\n"
            + ",address\n"
            + ",phone\n"
            + ",comments\n"
            + ",hire_date\n";            

    insertion += ")"
              + "VALUES\n"
              + getParameterQuestionMarks(numberOfParameters);

    return insertion;
}

// allow for multiple insertions
public static Object[][] getEmployeeParamters(List<Employee> employees)
{
    List<List<Object>> paramList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Employee employee : employees)
    {
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

        objectList.add(employee.getName());
        objectList.add(employee.getAddress());
        objectList.add(employee.getPhone());
        objectList.add(employee.getComments());
        objectList.add(employee.getHire_date());

        paramList.add(objectList);


    }

    return paramList.stream().map(u -> u.toArray(new Object[0])).toArray(Object[][]::new);

}

public static String getParameterQuestionMarks(int number)
{
    String paramterMarks = "(";
    for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++)
    {
        paramterMarks += "?";
        if ((x + 1) <= number)
        {
            paramterMarks += ",";
        }
    }
    paramterMarks += ")";

    return paramterMarks;
}
```

Then in your SQLManager class, your insert method is as such:

```
public void insertEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
{
    Connection connection = createConnection();

    try
    {
        new QueryRunner().insertBatch(connection, Employee.getEmployeeInsertStatement(), new ScalarHandler<>(), Employee.getEmployeeParameters(employees));


    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            DbUtils.close(connection);
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SQLManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }

}
```